# Adding a point to an existing layer

Tags: qgis-3, point, layers, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler

How can I create a point from two coordinates with the QGIS Modeling tool and add it to an existing layer?

Comment: just put the point anywhere on the map, then use the 'numerical vertex edit' tool to change the coordinates

Comment: I think OP wants to do that in a model, not manually.

Answer (score 10):

Create a new point using [Geometry by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression), than [Merge vector layers](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#merge-vector-layers) to merge this newly created point layer with the inital points layer. Here you can [download the model](https://drive.switch.ch/index.php/s/N4UJ9oTyIZEproC) for this workflow.

For manual input of x- and y-coordinate values that create the point, create two numbers. In geometry by expression, you can access these numbers (they are available as variables) to create the point: `make_point ( @xcoord , @ycoord )`.

[image]

Comment: +1. You have many sophisticated answers. Thanks for that. But it would be more useful if your application interface was in English. On an English website, another language (especially in gui) is like a noise for most people here. This is my opinion of course.

Comment: @user156679 thanks for sharing your thoughts. I added an english-language screenshot as well. The differences are not so big and I guess in most cases, it's easy to identify what corresponds to what. I try to write solutions in a way that the explanation from the text should be sufficient to understand how it works. The screenshots are more to illustrate the graphical interface: to see where to click, add an expression or insert some parameters. This should become clear regardless of language, I hope.

Comment: I would probably agree with @user156679 :)

Comment: @user156679 since it is rather lengthy to switch languages, you usually don't want to have that hassle when answering questions on the fly, if you every-day (work) GUI is in your native language. This is especially true, if you're the go-to-person when it comes to GIS-issues in your company, and you have to translate everything first before explaining some rather easy workflow to non-english speakers.

Comment: In geometry by expression you use a layer called "point" as input, what is that? Do you have another point layer as input to your model outside your screenshot?

Comment: @BERA thanks for drawing my attention to this. In a first version, using the model just on my machine, I had a point layer with this name as input. However, to share the model and to use it with whatever input, I adapted the screenshot now. See also the link to download the model.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I have two more questions:
1. Can I add data to the point like a the high for the wind turbine?
2. Can I add the point to the original layer so that I don't have an extra temporary layer? (I think the people who should use this would be confused with an extra layer)

Comment: 1. You can add a field calculator algorithm to the model to add a new attribue. 2. With this soulution, you have to create an temporary layer. I'm not sure if it's possible in a model to create a new point on an existing layer, based on x/y coordinate values.